# Option clash when using graphicx and tikz packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdftex, package-options

The following code fails `Option clash for package graphicx`, it seems to be an incompatibility between the package `graphicx` (when the option `pdftex` is used) and the package `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    The lazy dog...

\end{document}
```

I am currently working with Debian wheezy (updated as of 10th November 2012), and the latest TeXLive LaTeX distribution included.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: The `pdftex` option should *never* be passed to `graphicx`, which is able to guess it by itself.

Comment: TikZ loads `graphicx` automatically and both know what to do when you choose a driver.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `tikz` package already loaded the `graphicx` package, so you can't load it again. Trying to load it with different options will cause the "Option clash" error. You can use `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{graphicx}` before loading `tikz` to pass any additional options to the internally loaded `graphicx`. However, you do **not need and should not use the `pdftex` option** manually with modern LaTeX distributions. Packages which are driver dependent are very well capable to detect the right driver by themselves and providing a wrong one causes all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer. I already found out that what you say is correct: I do not need to call {pdftex}{graphicx}, eps figures included are automatically and correctly converted to .pdf by {graphicx}.

Answer (score 3):

Put the tikz package before the graphicx package, that's what I did when I had the same problem by using the final option of the graphicx packages with the tikz package and it works.