# Error trying to compile tikzpicture code

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

Some of my tikzpicture code won't compile anymore. The following code used to compile (2 years ago), but now I get

```
"ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Package pgf Error: No shape named B is known.

! Package pgf Error: No shape named B is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \WE(B){A}"
```

I have installed the latest pgf package, but it doesn't make a difference. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage {amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,verbatim,pgfpict2e}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-berge}

 \begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Dijkstra]
\tikzset{node distance = 5.25cm}
\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}= [thick]
\Vertices*{square}{E,D,C,B}
\tikzset{node distance = 2.75cm}
\WE(B){A}
\SO(B){G}
\WE(G){F}
\tikzset{node distance = 3cm}
\SOEA(B){H}

\Edge[label=$20$](A)(B)
\Edge[label=$70$](B)(C)
\Edge[label=$40$](A)(F)
\Edge[label=$30$](F)(G)
\Edge[label=$30$](G)(H)
\Edge[label=$20$](B)(H)
\Edge[label=$50$](H)(D)
\Edge[label=$70$](F)(E)
\Edge[label=$50$](E)(D)
\Edge[label=$50$](G)(D)
\Edge[label=$70$](C)(D)
\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not directly related to `pgf`, but to the `tkz` collection by Alain Matthes. I guess he has made updates to this (specifically `tkz-graph`) that makes your code not work.

You could of course try to find an older version of `tkz-graph`, but I would rather update the code. I don't know exactly how this was supposed to look, but the code below generates the following output:

[image]

The changes I made to the code:

- `\Vertices*` to `\Vertices`. The starred version of the command doesn't seem to do anything, so remove the `*`.
- `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset`: The latter is recommended, though the former still works. ([Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles))
- `\tikzset{node distance = ...}` to `\SetGraphUnit{}`: The former had no effect, but `tkz-graph` provides the latter that does a similar job I guess. For the `\Vertices` the `unit` is added as an optional argument.
- `\usepackage{tkz-berge}` to `\usepackage{tkz-graph}`. The former loads the latter, so this is not a big deal really, but the commands you use are really provided by `tkz-graph`.

Unrelated note: You shouldn't pass the `pdftex` option to `graphicx`, the packages can figure this out for themselves. See e.g. [this answer by Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82158/586)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Dijkstra]
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style ={thick}}
\Vertices[unit=5.25cm]{square}{E,D,C,B}
\SetGraphUnit{2.75cm}
\WE(B){A}
\SO(B){G}
\WE(G){F}
\SetGraphUnit{3cm}
\SOEA(B){H}

\Edge[label=$20$](A)(B)
\Edge[label=$70$](B)(C)
\Edge[label=$40$](A)(F)
\Edge[label=$30$](F)(G)
\Edge[label=$30$](G)(H)
\Edge[label=$20$](B)(H)
\Edge[label=$50$](H)(D)
\Edge[label=$70$](F)(E)
\Edge[label=$50$](E)(D)
\Edge[label=$50$](G)(D)
\Edge[label=$70$](C)(D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```